# I get no image when dynamically inserting a url in jss for backgroundImage. React, material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I can get the image statically displayed by importing it and using the variable in useStyles as in the following chunk:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core'
import Image from '../../Images/Shanghai.png'

const useStyles = makeStyles(img => ({
  image: {
    backgroundImage: 'url('+ image +')',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '10rem',
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
  }
}))

const ImageHeader = props => {
const img = props.img
const classes = useStyles(img)

return <Box sm={12} className={classes.image} />
    }

export default ImageHeader
```

but when I try a dynamic approach like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles(img => ({
  image: {
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + img + ')',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '10rem',
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
  }
}))
```

No image is displayed and I get this value:

```
 backgroundImage: url([object object])
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: url() is waiting for a string like format. It looks like it receives an object, did you try to console.log(img) to see what the object looks like ?

Comment: Yes, if I console.log(img) I get the string value of the url. So it should work as far as I know.., but it doesnt.

Comment: Are you sure it is a string, it shouldn't show as object

Comment: The parameter passed to the function in `makeStyles` is the theme. You just happen to be calling the theme `img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#returns-3):

> useStyles. It accepts one argument: the properties that will be used
>   for "interpolation" in the style sheet.

Basically, the argument in `makeStyles` callback represents your `theme` which is an object. In order to use the argument passed to `useStyles` in `makeStyles`'s callback, you have to use the callback approach for the `backgroundImage` property.

```js
...
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({ // <---------- theme is an object
  image: {
    backgroundImage: (image) => 'url('+ image +')', // <---------- like this
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '10rem',
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
  }
}))

const ImageHeader = props => {
const img = props.img
const classes = useStyles(img)
...
```

Comment: Thanks gdh, I referred back to MUI documentation as you suggested, problem solved!